# SWIFT - String based Key-Value Array decoding?

Tags: macos, decoding, swift4.2

I have a String based Key-Value Array inside of a String, and I want to decoded it and assign the value to an existing array in Swift 4.2. For example:

```
let array: [String:String] = []
let stringToDecode = “[\“Hello\”:\”World\”, \"Key\":\"Value\"]”

// I want ‘array’ to be assigned 
// to the value that is inside 
// ‘stringToDecode’
```

I’ve tried the JSON decoder, but it couldn’t decode it. Is there a simple way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: this is a dictionary and not an array. Can your stringToDecode be longer?

Comment: Yah sure! Sorry, I thought that gave a good enough example. I'll update the post :)

Comment: It's updated, not sure how good my memory is with the String-based Key Value type, but please feel free to correct me if I got it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try using a library like [SwiftyJson](https://learnappmaking.com/swift-json-swiftyjson/), it makes working with json much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I just recently found a way. Basically, I just encoded the array to a JSON format, converted it to a String from Data, then decoded it and assigned it to a variable. Hard work, phew! XD